# JavaScript check pushed Arrays steps based on another Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating an interactive step checker using JavaScript and i want to check if the new array value being pushed is correct based on a step array. i can do it after all items has been pushed on the array but i need to be in real-time.

My current code to check, but i need to check every push or before it gets push.

```
var steps = ["Step1", "Step2", "Step3", "Step4", "Step5"];
var user_steps = [];
var user_value = document.querySelector("#input");

//onclick event

user_steps.push(user_value);

if(JSON.stringify(user_steps)==JSON.stringify(steps){
   console.log("Steps was followed);
}else{
   console.log("Steps not followed");
}
```

Comment: `if(steps[user_steps.length] === user_value)`

Comment: Where do `user_value` come from ?

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic content check the equality each time when you append a new item to the array

Function listen for click event

```js
function addNewData(event) {
  var data = document.querySelector("input[name='data']");
  user_steps.push(data.value);
  isEqual = checkEquality(steps, user_steps);
   // Update DOM Content
  updateDOMContent();
}
```

Check the equality each time

```js
function checkEquality(content_1, content_2) {
  return JSON.stringify(content_1) === JSON.stringify(content_2);
}
```

As seen from addNewData function on each addition event add an item to the list and check for the equality and update other required items according to the result.

Check CodePen for example

https://codepen.io/alihuseyn/pen/YzzqeRe

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like so:

```js
let steps = ["Step1", "Step2", "Step3", "Step4", "Step5"];
let user_steps = [];
let user_value = document.querySelector("#input");


// onclick event
let pos = user_steps.length - 1;
if (steps[pos] === user_steps[pos]) {
  console.log("Steps were followed");
} else {
  console.warn("Steps were not followed");
}


// onsubmit event-- check all to ensure order is correct
let isValid = steps.every((v, i) => v === user_steps[i]);
console.log(`Steps were ${isValid?'':'not'} valid`);
```

I threw in a check for you for your submit to ensure the order is still valid.

Hope this helps,